# Inputting data in SQLite database from txt takes unusual long time

Tags: python, sqlite

I have some hundred text files of ; separated values, each file being 200-300 mb large. I suspect that the problem is that the values that is inputted in two columns, with each column having an index, have six digit decimals.

This is the SQLite table, created in python:

```
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE MessageType1(port int, userid int, longitude INT, latitude INT, cog INT, heading INT, unixtime int)")
    cur.execute("CREATE INDEX latitude_index ON MessageType1 (latitude)")
    cur.execute("CREATE INDEX longitude_index ON MessageType1 (longitude)")
```

The values is inputted by using this script:

```
for f in *.txt
do
    sqlite3 -separator ';' database/database.db ".import $f MessageType1"
    echo ${f%.*}.database
done
```

Typical input is:

```
32;25743255;70.384123;59.693545;261.60;242.00;134433400
```

After some testing, I've found that inputting one file into the database could take upwards of three hours. Should I try to decrease the number of decimals?

Comment: The problem is most likely that you're not starting a transaction. Doing inserts outside of a transaction (or rather doing a transaction per INSERT) in SQLite is expensive because of the additional checks and journalling that has to happen at the start and end of each transaction. Wrap the process in a BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT and things will be MUCH faster

Comment: I believed that I did not need to make a transaction for a simple sqlite import? http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Comment: I think .import just runs inserts over and over, so I'd think you'd still need to start a transaction. Try it manually in the shell?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I find it hard to find out how I work with transactions in SQLite CLI, it isn't mentioned here https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: As an aside, I notice you're inputting lats and longs, have you looked at the R*Tree module? It might be of interest: https://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html

Comment: Do the import without indexes.

Comment: Can I add indexes in retrospect? The indexes is added to better differntiate between the data when it should be exported later.